# Is it possible to create a variable in Typescript that can be any value as long as it adheres to a certain format?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, types

for example, i need a representation that would allow any value that is a combination of two strings separated by a "_"
so i tried something like this:

```
var key:string = string + "" + string;
```

after typing it though, i realized that it obviously wouldn't work..

i know that for Objects, Typescript allows us to use interfaces to define allowed keys/values, but what about for other stuff?

new to this, so i'd like to apologize if i'm going in the completely wrong direction

Comment: So essentially you want compile time validation on input variables based on some pattern?

Comment: The closest thing I think you can get is string literal types - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

Comment: thanks for the reponse,  

i have tried that ("string literal types"), but it only worked with explicit strings, not something like a combination of any string and a specific string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible in typescript. On GitHub there is an open suggestion to implement regex validated string types so the best you can do is to vote for it or work on this suggestion :)

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579

If you just want to check at runtime if the string matches the pattern of to strings connected with "_" you can achieve it with regex matching:

```
function checkString(stringToCheck: string) {
    const regex = /.+_.+/g;
    return stringToCheck && stringToCheck.match(regex) !== null
}
```

Comment: the `&&` operator returns the first value if it is falsy, so the rest of this statement is only validated if the variable `stringToCheck` has a truthy value, in this case a valid string. This short form of validating is an old JavaScript habit, with the `strictNullChecks` Typescript compiler option it is theoretically obsolete, because the compiler will complain whenever a value is used which can be null or undefined